Optix denoiser implementation exhibits black square artifacts
I integrated Optix denoiser inside my path tracer using Optix 8.0.0 and Cuda 12.6.
While I get decent results with some scenes, I get black square artefacts on some other scenes after several path tracing samples.

Please see this video for a demo description:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/u9cjtutafd2835nx4cvxa/optix_issue.mp4?rlkey=65yjubk2vprllf2ko27qmfecw&st=88bqlsae&dl=0
At 100 samples per pixel(glitch is already there) gbuffer/aovs looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j94a6mnib7ddcgugb2wmq/gBuffer.zip?rlkey=x4b1985pp276hmc6c9t5la6f0&st=6y9e3jp3&dl=0
Meaning the denoiser input is good.
What am I missing? My implementation is straightforward. I use the unmodified denoiser wrapper from the toolkit(OptiXDenoiser.h).
Header
#include "OptiXDenoiser.h"//SDK wrapper

struct NvidiaOptixDenoiser
{
    NvidiaOptixDenoiser();
    ~NvidiaOptixDenoiser();

    void denoise(Graphics::Texture::Image& imageOut, const DenoisingArgs& denoisingArgs);

private:
    OptiXDenoiser* m_denoiser = nullptr;
    nbBool m_firstFrame = true;
};

CPP:
NvidiaOptixDenoiser::NvidiaOptixDenoiser()
{
    m_denoiser = new OptiXDenoiser();
}

NvidiaOptixDenoiser::~NvidiaOptixDenoiser()
{
    m_denoiser->finish();
    delete m_denoiser;
}

void NvidiaOptixDenoiser::denoise(Graphics::Texture::Image& imageOut, const DenoisingArgs& denoisingArgs)
{
    ASSERT(imageOut.getFormat() == ImageFormat::RGB32F);
    RGB32FImage* imageRGBFOut = dynamic_cast<RGB32FImage*>(&imageOut);
    ASSERT(imageRGBFOut);

    const Graphics::GBuffer* gBuffer = denoisingArgs.gBuffer;
    ASSERT(gBuffer);

    const std::unique_ptr<Graphics::Texture::RGB32FImage>& imageIn = gBuffer->m_radiance;

    const Uint32 width = imageOut.getWidth();
    const Uint32 height = imageOut.getHeight();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Build the input images. Optix Denoiser only support FLOAT4. Maybe just a limitation of the wrapper?
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RGBA32FImage optixSrcColor(width, height);
    RGBA32FImage optixNormals(width, height);
    RGBA32FImage optixAlbedo(width, height);
    RGBA32FImage optixFlow(width, height);
    const Uint32 optixNbPixels = width * height;

    tbb::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(optixNbPixels), [&](size_t tbbIdx) {
        const Uint32 pixelIdx = (nbUint32)tbbIdx;

        const Uint32 pixelPosX = (nbUint32)(pixelIdx % width);
        const Uint32 pixelPosY = (nbUint32)(pixelIdx / width);
        const Math::Uvec2 pixelPos = Math::Uvec2(pixelPosX, pixelPosY);

        {
            // In color.
            {
                const RGBFColor color = imageIn->getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
                optixSrcColor.setPixelFromPosition(RGBAFColor(color.x, color.y, color.z, 0.0f), pixelPos);
            }

            // Normals.
            {
                const RGBFColor normal = gBuffer->m_normals->getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
                optixNormals.setPixelFromPosition(RGBAFColor(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z, 0.0f), pixelPos);
            }

            // Albedo.
            {
                const RGBFColor albedo = gBuffer->m_albedo->getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
                optixAlbedo.setPixelFromPosition(RGBAFColor(albedo.x, albedo.y, albedo.z, 0.0f), pixelPos);
            }

            // In flow. They are motion vectors
            {
                const RGBFColor flow = denoisingArgs.gBuffer->m_motionVectors->getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
                optixFlow.setPixelFromPosition(RGBAFColor(flow.x, flow.y, flow.z, 0.0f), pixelPos);
            }
        }
    });

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Build the Optix input data
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    RGBA32FImage optixDestColor(width, height);

    OptiXDenoiser::Data optixDenoisingData;
    optixDenoisingData.width = width;
    optixDenoisingData.height = height;
    optixDenoisingData.color = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(optixSrcColor.getRawData());
    optixDenoisingData.normal = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(optixNormals.getRawData());
    optixDenoisingData.albedo = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(optixAlbedo.getRawData());
    optixDenoisingData.flow = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(optixFlow.getRawData());

    optixDenoisingData.outputs.push_back(reinterpret_cast<float*>(optixDestColor.getMutableRawData()));

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Perform denoising
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (m_firstFrame)
    {
        m_denoiser->init(optixDenoisingData, 0, 0, false, true, false, false, 0, false);
        m_firstFrame = false;
    }
    else
    {
        m_denoiser->update(optixDenoisingData);
    }

    m_denoiser->exec();
    m_denoiser->getResults();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Read back results
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    tbb::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(optixNbPixels), [&](size_t tbbIdx) {
        const Uint32 pixelIdx = (nbUint32)tbbIdx;

        const Uint32 pixelPosX = (nbUint32)(pixelIdx % width);
        const Uint32 pixelPosY = (nbUint32)(pixelIdx / width);
        const Math::Uvec2 pixelPos = Math::Uvec2(pixelPosX, pixelPosY);

        const RGBAFColor color = optixDestColor.getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
        imageRGBFOut->setPixelFromPosition(RGBFColor(color.x, color.y, color.z), pixelPos);
    });
}

Thanks for helping!

Links to videos is tricky, but don't expect too many people to download stuff from some Internet Rando's dropbox.

Gotcha :) I think i also gave a proper text description

Totally unrelated note: You can save yourself from some Rule of Three Woes by replacing OptiXDenoiser* m_denoiser = nullptr; with std::unique_ptr<OptiXDenoiser> m_denoiser; Docs for std::unique_ptr

Consider embedding a representative frame as a static image in the question, but yeah, I think you'll be fine with what you have. Maybe upgrade the code example to a [mre].
